# spark-submit --keytab option does not copy the file to executors

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

In my case I am using Spark (2.1.1) and for the processing I need to connect to Kafka (using kerberos, therefore a keytab).

When submitting the job I can pass the keytab with --keytab and --principal options. The main drawback is that the keytab will no be send to the distributed cache (or at least be available to the executors) so it will fail.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
...
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Could not login: the client is being asked for a password, but the Kafka client code does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. not available to garner`  authentication information from the user
```

If I try passing it also in --files it works (version 2.1.0) but in this latest version (2.1.1) it is not allowed because it failes due to:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempt to add (file:keytab.keytab) multiple times to the distributed cache.
```

Any tips?

Comment: I read somewhere that the management of Kerberos delegation tokens (for HDFS, HBase, Hive... but not Kafka!) has been refactored in Spark 2.1.1, that may be why Spark now secretly ships the keytab to HDFS.

Comment: Did you simply try renaming the target file, i.e. `--files /wtf/wtf/keytab.keytab#tmp.keytab` which is supposed to upload `tmp.keytab` in the working dir of each YARN container? It had quirks in early versions, cf. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10858 but it should be stable now.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter yes I tried but I guess it compares the source name, and it fails complaining of uploading two times the same file. And concerning the first, I dont know if it secretly uploads it or not, but the fact is that is not available. The solution I have for now is to create a symlink in the machine where I submit the job, send it in yarn-client mode with the symlink as keytab and the proper keytab file in --files. But is not a nice one...

Comment: I would have tried exactly the same thing, in your place. Hopefully some future version of Spark will use a random temp name for the keytab passed via `--keytab` and you will be able to remove your workaround...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this issue making a copy of my keytab file (e.g. original file is `osboo.keytab` and its copy `osboo-copy-for-kafka.keytab`) and pushing it to HDFS via `--files` option.

```
# Call
spark2-submit --keytab osboo.keytab \
 --principal osboo \
--files osboo-copy-for-kafka.keytab#osboo-copy-for-kafka.keytab,kafka.jaas#kafka.jaas

# kafka.jaas
KafkaClient {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
keyTab="osboo-copy-for-kafka.keytab"
principal="osboo@REALM.COM"
serviceName="kafka";
};

Client {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
keyTab="osboo-copy-for-kafka.keytab"
serviceName="zookeeper"
principal="osboo@REALM.COM";
};
```

Maybe this solution requires less efforts to keep in mind symlinks between files so I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

spark-submit --keytab option copy the file with different name in the local container dir when you submit app on yarn.

you can find this in lauch_container.sh

[lauch_container.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOaUz.png)